# Is there any other way I can say " W and X have helped me develop Y and Z skills?"

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to say my internship and project have helped me develop research and analytical skills but in a different way. How should I do it?

Comment: Different how? What's wrong with "my internship helped me develop research and analytical skills?"

Comment: well actually i have already written  "so n so subjects have helped me develop a srong quantitative background" so this was sounding repetetive

Comment: I learned Z and W while working with X and Y.  X and Y were essential/instrumental/helpful when I was getting started with Z and W.

Answer (score 1):

You can always connect project and internship: "My internship project....." Or "The project I worked on during my internship...." You could also drop the research bit, as research is an analytical skill. And/or you could always drop the analytical part and just say "research skills".

**EXAMPLES**: My internship project has helped me to develop my research skills.

My internship project has helped me to develop my analytical skills.

My internship project has helped me to develop my analytical research skills.

The project I worked on during my internship has helped me to develop my analytical skills.

The project I worked on during my internship has helped me to develop my analytical research skills.